# Understand the example for Simple 3-layer MLP using MXNet in Julia

Tags: julia, mnist, mxnet, mxnet.jl

I have a basic understanding of neural networks. I understand that there should be a y matrix (expected result)  which stores 0 or 1 corresponding to different category labels. As an example, for digit recognition, if the number to be identified is 6 then the y vector should be `[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]`. However, when I see the MXNet example [in MXNet.jl repository on Github](https://github.com/dmlc/MXNet.jl), I could not identify any code which prepares this kind of result matrix. I think the magic lies in the `get_mnist_providers()` method which returns 2 providers:

```
train_provider, eval_provider = get_mnist_providers(batch_size)
```

I have no idea what these providers are - train_provider, eval_provider.
Please help me understand these providers. I am trying to write an algorithm which has different classifications, so understanding this provider is vital.

Comment: The example I am referring to is present here - https://github.com/dmlc/MXNet.jl

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer once your question has been answered. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

You are right as to providing the y vector corresponding to labels. In MXNet there is the concept of iterators. The iterators are used to bind the data to the labels. What your get_mnist_providers method is probably doing is providing the data iterator which has the corresponding label attached to it.

For a more detailed understanding on how data iterators fit into the whole picture of model optimization, you can try this tutorial (links to [mxnet-notebooks](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet-notebooks/) Github repository):
[linear-regression.ipynb](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet-notebooks/blob/29d602a1f81e2da71e9e517796e7a24467b650ba/python/tutorials/linear-regression.ipynb)

(You will need jupyter notebook to run the tutorial. just pip install jupyter and then run the command 'jupyter notebook' in the folder where the tutorial file exists)

Comment: Thanks for explaining.

Comment: The actual function definition for `get_mnist_providers()` can be found in the repository the OP linked to, dmlc/MXNet.jl, in the file [mnist-data.jl](https://github.com/dmlc/MXNet.jl/blob/master/examples/mnist/mnist-data.jl#L1)